# DataSet и BinaryFormatter

Tags: .net, сериализация

Почему `DataSet` при использовании `BinaryFormatter` по прежнему человеко-читаем в выходном файле и похож на XML?

Я ожидал там увидеть не читаемый бинарник.

Comment: Помню такую древнюю [статью](https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/DotNetSerial.xml) про сериализацию датасета.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос "почему":

У датасета есть свойство [RemotingFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataTable.RemotingFormat?view=netframework-4.7.2). По умолчанию оно равно `Xml`, можно установить в `Binary`.

А вот "зачем" так сделано, затрудняюсь сказать. Ведь если кому-то нужен формат xml, то можно использовать `XmlSerializer` или `DataContractSerializer`.